# Practical use of improper lists in Erlang (perhaps all functional languages)

Tags: list, functional-programming, erlang

I've been reading *Erlang and OTP in action*, and stumbled upon a question with regards to improper lists.

> Don’t be tempted to use list cells
>   this way even if you think you have a
>   clever idea — it’s bug-prone and
>   confuses both humans and program
>   analysis tools. That said, there are
>   one or two valid uses for creating
>   improper lists, but they’re considered
>   advanced programming techniques and
>   are beyond the scope of this book.

Out of scope for the book? It must be perfect for Stackoverflow!
So my question is, of course, what would some valid uses would be?

Comment: Just in case, you cannot construct improper lists in Haskell because of type system. It wouldn't make sense.

Comment: `data ListImproper a = Nil | Cons a (ListImproper a) | Improper a a` :)

Comment: I was reading the same book and came stackoverflow to ask the same question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One use suggested by Erlang documentation is [faking lazy lists](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.8/doc/programming_examples/funs.html):

```
-module(lazy).
-export([ints_from/1]).
ints_from(N) ->
    fun() ->
            [N|ints_from(N+1)]
    end.
```

Answer (score 5):

One valid use is described at the very bottom of the [Eunit user manual](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#id57727), in the section about lazy generators.  This code example is supposed to create a very long list that will be consumed one element at a time, so instead of generating the entire list at once it creates an improper list whose tail describes how to generate the rest of the list:

```
lazy_test_() ->
    lazy_gen(10000).
lazy_gen(N) ->
    {generator,
     fun () ->
         if N > 0 ->
                [?_test(...)
                 | lazy_gen(N-1)];
            true ->
                []
         end
     end}.
```

In other words, it's a lazy list, which Erlang itself doesn't give you.

Comment: This sounds like a continuing fraction.

Answer (score 4):

OTP stdlib dictionary implementation dict module is using improper lists for key-value pairs.
The justification is 2-tuple uses 1 word more memory than 2-element improper list. See
[efficiency guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) for details

Comment: It was done as a private joke, only those looking at the code would actually notice it. The savings are very small and it is defined in a macro so it is easy to change if anyone is really disturbed by it. :-)

Comment: Hmm, even though the source confirms this, in both R13B04 and R14B01 for me `dict:append(apa, hest, dict:new())` yields:
`{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{...},{{[],[[apa,hest]],...}}}`

Answer (score 1):

OTP standard [digraph](http://erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html#add_vertex-1) module for directed graphs uses improper lists for tagged vertex and edge identifiers. For example, vertex 42 would be identified as ['$v'|42], which means a pair of an atom (no, not a character literal!) and an integer, similarly edge 97 would be ['$e'|97].