# About the | operator in erlang.

Tags: erlang

We can make a nested list in erlang by writing something like this:

```
 NL = [[2,3], [1]]. 
 [[2,3],[1]]
```

But assume we wrote it like this instead:

```
 OL = [[2,3]|1].
 [[2,3]|1]
```

Is OL still a list? Can someone please elaborate more what OL is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called an *improper list* and should typically not be used. I think most library functions expects proper lists (e.g. length([1|2]) throws bad argument exception). Pattern matching with improper lists works though.

For some use cases, see [Practical use of improper lists in Erlang (perhaps all functional languages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088575/practical-use-of-improper-lists-in-erlang-perhaps-all-functional-languages)

Answer (score 3):

More information about `|` and building list is given in [Functional Programming: what is an "improper list"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list/1922724#1922724) .