# What is the effect on using | without a list?

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

I was doing this in iex:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.3.0-dev) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> a = [1]
[1]
iex(2)> b = [a | [2]]
[[1], 2]
iex(3)> [head | tail] = b
[[1], 2]
iex(4)> head
[1]
iex(5)> tail
[2]
iex(6)> n = [1]
[1]
iex(7)> o = [1 | 2]
[1 | 2]
iex(8)> [h | t] = o
[1 | 2]
iex(9)> h
1
iex(10)> t
2
```

What is/is there the/a difference between the above usages of `|`, and why is iex displaying them as `[[1], [2]]` and `[1 | 2]`?

Comment: It's an improper list; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20164531/409228).

Comment: Even if it is known as an improper list  Steve - that doesn't explain why Elixir seems to  prefer it in the Iex shell.

Comment: Elixir isn't preferring anything. `[1|2]` is an improper list, and `[1,2]` is a proper list, as is `[[1],2]`.